# Changed lines highlight in VS Code

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to show the line Edited and Saved since the file is opened (without using any version control) with one color, and the line Edited but not saved yet with another color? Just like the screenshot I uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've just found an extension that do it without using version control, its name is: `Show Unsaved Changes` and here's the link to this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.show-unsaved-changes