# how to see highlighted rows that have been edited

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I used to see which rows are edited (compared to last commit) in visual code studio, but on my new mac, it's not there anymore. Although I have git in the folder. How do I switch this on?

UPDATE: I found out it was the extension Gitlens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're talking about gutter highlight.

Check: [Changed lines highlight in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953512/changed-lines-highlight-in-vs-code)

Without a good image to show what you are talking about it's hard to know.

If it's not that, try Gitlens. If still not that, try to reinstall the Git Client. There are reports of this failing sometimes.

Comment: `reinstall Git on VSC`???? The thing the OP is looking for is build in VSC, you can't install Git on VSC

Comment: My mistake @rioV8, I wanted to say to reinstall the Git Client.

Comment: I used to have the green line before the lines of code that were new (compared to last git commit) in the screenshot in your link. I didn't have that plugin. It could have been another plugin, thanks for your help!

Comment: It was gitlens! :) yahoo

Comment: @ObaApi just remember to accept the answer to close the topic.